# AngularJS Выбор одного элемента массива

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get('/db/event/') 
.then(function(response) {
...
});
```

`response.data` возвращает массив:

```
[{"status":"trial","number":"88888","time":"1512574955","updated_at":"2017-12-03 19:13:56"}]
```

Как можно из этого массива в `$scope.status` поместить только `status`?

Comment: возможно `$scope.status = response.data[0].status`

Comment: Спасибо. Именно так!

Comment: ну вы почитайте материал по этой теме, а именно [вот про объекты](http://learn.javascript.ru/object) и [вот про массивы](http://learn.javascript.ru/array). Вот ещё полезные ссылки: [1](http://learn.javascript.ru/first-steps). [2](http://learn.javascript.ru/data-structures). [3](http://learn.javascript.ru/)

Comment: Обязательно ознакомлюсь! Спасибо ещё раз